# Sort an array exactly like example string

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, sorting, nlp

What would be the optimal solution for the following problem?

I have

```
original_string = "This is a string that I am trying to sort"
```

I also have

```
array_to_sort = ['sort', 'string', 'This is', 'I', 'trying to', 'am', 'a']
```

I need to sort the array, so that elements are in the same order as in string. The elements are sometimes grouped together, but always in the same way as they are in string (i.e. there can be no 'is This' element in the array, only 'This is')..

All this is happening within the Rails application, so I was thinking of maybe taking the database approach and saving elements in database and then using some keys to reconstruct the original_string.. but maybe just doing some .sort trick is better.. The result does not necessarily have to be an array, can be anything..

Thanks for any input.

P.S. including an nlp tag, because this is a result of some nlp exercise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
array_to_sort.sort_by { |substr| original_string.index(substr) }
```

The result is a new array, sorted by the position of the substring in the original string.

If you want to sort in-place (by changing the original array), you can use the `sort_by!` method instead.

Obviously, it's too stupid to detect doubles (i.e. `"I am what I am", ["I am", "I am", "what"]` will not be sorted as one hopes).

**EDIT** Making it not quite so stupid is not quite so trivial:

```
def get_all_positions(str, substr)                                                                                                                                                                                           
  pattern = Regexp.new('\b' + Regexp::escape(substr) + '\b')
  result = []
  pos = -1
  while match = pattern.match(str, pos + 1)
    pos = match.offset(0)[0] + 1
    result << pos
  end
  result
end

def sort_array_according_to_string(arr, str, i=0, positions=nil)
  positions ||= Hash.new
  if i < arr.count
    current = arr[i]
    current_positions = get_all_positions(str, current)
    result = []
    current_positions.each do |pos|
      if !positions[pos]
        positions[pos] = [pos, i, current]
        result += sort_array_according_to_string(arr, str, i + 1, positions)
        positions.delete(pos)
      end
    end
  else
    sorted = positions
      .values
      .sort_by { |position, i| position }
      .map { |position, i| arr[i] }
    result = [sorted]
  end
  if i == 0
    result.uniq!
  end
  result
end

original_string = 'this is what this is not'
example_array = ['this', 'is', 'is not', 'what', 'this']
solution = sort_array_according_to_string(example_array, original_string)
puts solution.inspect
```

Comment: Won't String#index find the first occurrence anywhere in the string?(without considering if it's a full word)

Comment: They will. I just reread the question, and them being words was not specified. If they need to be words, you can deal with it by regexp-quoting the substring, surrounding with word-boundary matchers, then compare the length of the pre-match.

Comment: can you give an example? Sorry for this postscriptum, but the original_string can be rather complex in my case..

Comment: Example for what? Matching only full words?

Comment: For the case where the words will repeat for example original_string = 'This string has information about string theory' and example_array = ['This','string', 'information about', 'has', 'theory', 'string'] Thanks )